# SwiftLint cannot exclude Pods folder

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, swiftlint

I configure `.swiftlint.yml` file on the root path of project.

1. `.swiftlint.yml`:

```
disabled_rules: 
  - colon
  - comma
  - control_statement
  - trailing_whitespace
opt_in_rules: 
  - empty_count
  - missing_docs
included: 
  - Searcher
excluded: 
  - Carthage
  - Pods
  - Searcher/AppDelegate.swift
  - Searcher/SceneDelegate.swift
```

2. Project structure

```
Searcher
├── .swiftlint.yml
├── Podfile
├── Pods
├── Searcher
```

3. Build phases > Run Script

```
${PODS_ROOT}/SwiftLint/swiftlint
```

SwiftLint can exclude `Searcher/AppDelegate.swift` but not `Pods/SnapKit`. How can I correct it please?

Comment: Can you share your Xcode Project Navigator? Are you opening .xcworkspace or .xcodeproj file?

Comment: I'm opening .xcworkspace file, so the build is successful, but it shows a lot of warnings.

Comment: You can fix them or you can disable some warning. Check github page of SwiftLint :)

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this?